# 404 not found on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apache2, perl, localhost

I have installed Apache2 and perl on ubuntu 15.10. When i try to run a perl program on the server it says.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /cgi-bin/test.pl was not found on this server.
```

But i'm able to execute this on the terminal. Please help.

Comment: What's in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you try to access the program's URL?

Answer (score -1):

You have to install *perl* first on Ubuntu

please execute the command

```
apt-get install -y perl
```

If it is installed give try to run

```
& perl script.pl
```

Comment: I have already installed perl. As i specified i'm able to run this on the terminal. But not on the browser.

Comment: Which command or program you are using to run perl script/file?

Comment: perl filename.pl

Comment: Perl is used quite often on Ubuntu so it is installed by default and you actually can't remove it without breaking the system. And the error doesn't say that the script can't be run.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is i'm not able to run it on the server.